# Can switching power settings on a laptop during an update affect the battery?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, power-supply, battery

I recently had to move my laptop, and it started some planned updates as I was shutting it down. Being in a hurry, I unplugged the power cable and packed it, figuring that the laptop would just finish updating on its own power, and once it was done, I packed the computer and left.

Now, looking back, it is kind of a stupid thing to do, but I know that the laptop's power settings automatically change when it's unplugged, although as far as I know it just throttles everything down to conserve energy.

When booting the computer back up, I noticed that the battery was stuck at 95%. It recognizes that it is plugged, but it is not charging. I looked at other posts detailing problems like that, but none of them were similar. Furthermore, the computer then apparently crashed and restarted while I was away, and the event log tells nothing but an unexpected restart.

The only other different factor is that I used a different plug for the power brick, i.e. not the brick itself but the cable that plugs into the outlet.

I am using a ASUS TUF A17 laptop and Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

That's not something that would damage the battery. Sounds like you have a random hardware failure.

The battery isn't charging now because the computer thinks the charge is high and charging it will reduce battery's lifespan without doing much good. In my experience most laptops will do this over the 90% threshold (ie. if you plug it in and it's already ≥90% it won't start charging, but will run on AC power).

Try discharging the battery until the laptop turns off by itself (either gracefully or it just runs out of power), then charge it to 100%. Check if it starts working normally. If it doesn't, repeat.

If that doesn't help, you're out of luck. You may keep using the battery like that, but you'll have to assume that the remaining power indicator can't be trusted. It may fix itself at some point, but there are no guarantees. It can also break again later.

> The only other different factor is that I used a different plug for the power brick, i.e. not the brick itself but the cable that plugs into the outlet.

That doesn't matter. It's a random coincidence.

Comment: Strange thing is that it never happened until this point. Everytime I (briefly) used the computer on its own power, it charged back to 100%. I'll try letting it uncharge completely and see what it does. I guess the crash and restart was unrelated then.